# weird behavior when add property inside propertyMissing method

Tags: groovy

I wanted to implement functionally, which allows to add unknown properties to the class, during the attempt to set it without using `map` of dynamic properties.

As Groovy allows to  do it using `metaClass` I used it in `propertyMissing` method.

```
class Item {
    def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
        this.class.metaClass."$name" = value
    }
}
```

But I ran into a weird behavior.

```
def i1 = new Item()

i1.prop = "value"
println i1.properties // [class:class Item]
println i1.prop // null

i1.metaClass.field = "555"
println i1.properties // [prop:null, class:class Item, field:555]
println i1.prop // null

i1.prop = "value1"
println i1.properties // [prop:value1, class:class Item, field:555]
println i1.prop // value1
```

Also If I access `metaClass` before trying to set `prop` in the example it won't add it anymore

```
def i1 = new Item()
i1.metaClass.unkn = "1111"

i1.prop = "value"
println i1.properties // [class:class Item, unkn:1111]
println i1.prop // null

i1.metaClass.field = "555"
println i1.properties // [class:class Item, unkn:1111, field:555]
println i1.prop // null

i1.prop = "value1"
println i1.properties // [class:class Item, unkn:1111, field:555]
println i1.prop // null
```

Why it has such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update dynamically the metaclass of an object, Groovy replace the metaclass with an ExpandoMetaClass. It's a special implementation of a MetaClass which support adding and removing properties/methods.

However, in your example, `Item` is a `GroovyObject`, which have a persistent field on the MetaClass. this field is not updated when the MetaClass is exchanged : Only the metaclass in the registry is replaced by an ExpandoMetaClass. This kind of code can work with a javaobject, because this object doesn't have a field, and the resolution class->metaclass is done every time groovy access the metaclass.

In you know you are going to add properties on a groovy object, you should explicitly set an ExpandoMetaClass :

```
class Item {

    def Item() {
      def mc = new ExpandoMetaClass(Item, false, true)
      mc.initialize()
      this.metaClass = mc
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
        this.metaClass."$name" = value
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues you have is that you're trying to add a property to the class `MetaClass` instead of the instance `MetaClass`. And because you're adding the property *after* creating the instance, the instance doesn't see it. For example, this code fails to print the property:

```
class A { }

def a = new A()

A.metaClass.prop = 'value'

println a.prop
```

The error is rather interesting: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: prop for class: A
Possible solutions: prop`

However, even if you change the code to use the instance `MetaClass` it still doesn't work:

```
class Item {
    def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
        metaClass."$name" = value
    }
}

def i1 = new Item()

i1.prop = 'value'
assert i1.prop == 'value'
```

The error provides a clue:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: prop for class: groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
```

The `MetaClass` which provides the `Map`-like functionality is `ExpandoMetaClass`. Objects don't typically get this type of `MetaClass` until you do something like this:

```
instance.metaClass.prop = 'value'
```

So the fact that the `MetaClass` is not an `ExpandoMetaClass` means that replacement process is not happening. It's likely that `propertyMissing()` gets called too late in the MOP process to use the `MetaClass` in this way.

You mentioned that you want to add properties *without* using a `Map` of dynamic properties. However, `ExpandoMetaClass`, which is what you're attempting to use indirectly, uses...

...`Map`s of dynamic properties! You can see it [here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/f3c258a1169a201487fc4396d316ab9fab06e209/src/main/groovy/lang/ExpandoMetaClass.java).

The easiest way to achieve the behavior you're looking for is to *extend* `Expando`:

```
class Item extends Expando {
    def anotherProperty = 'Hello'
}

def i1 = new Item()

i1.prop = 'value'
assert i1.prop == 'value'
assert i1.anotherProperty == 'Hello'
```

`Expando` does all of the work for you. If you want to see how it works, read [this](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/d3bc07e5c2af7f5fbd344a961d549772de0680c7/src/main/groovy/util/Expando.java).

Comment: Oh I see. I completely overlooked that exception had MetaClassImpl. I just saw MissingPropertyException and did not look further...